# Errors in Deploying workbrain through weblogic

Tags: deployment, error-handling, weblogic, weblogic11g

So I'm kind of new to using weblogic, but I've been trying to deploy an ear file onto weblogic, (a workbrain ear file to be exact). I have tried exploding the ear file and deploying the folder and also deploying the ear file directly but i get the following errors after i click deploy :

[image: Error of deployment]

I have gone through google and found out things to edit XML files, not sure if it could be the ear file itself (it shouldn't be) or the weblogic server itself. It also said view the log files but im not sure where they are located

Any ideas of how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Chances are you are missing a necessary jar in your classpath. That said, you should check the admin server log for better information. The admin console doesn't really show much. Go look in `<domain home>/servers/AdminServer/logs` and see the full stack trace.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp I've read some documenation and it seems i need these classpaths .. `( C:\bea10.3\modules\
javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar;
C:\bea10.3\user_projects\domains\jdbc\ojdbc6.jar;
C:\bea10.3\jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32\lib\tools.jar;
C:\bea10.3\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;
C:\bea10.3\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\webservices.jar; )` .... how exactly do i know where i am missing the class path ( is it in a particular script, (i.e startWebLogic.cmd, commEnv.cmd) that the path is missing ?